# Animation goes like "fast" or with low fps

Tags: android, chronometer

I'm creating a counter that have an animation that takes the number in and out. I have this animation in an xml layout, and normally is runned once per second. My animations do things extrange as you can see in the following [video](http://youtu.be/LyFcMhrySRo), it doesn't ork properly.

My xml code for the animation is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale 
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="2.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="2.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="350"/>

    <scale 
        android:fromXScale="2.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="2.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="350"/>
</set>
```

And my code for the "chronometer" that reads the time of the system and start the animation and change the number is:

```
void onTime() { //this function is executed more than 1 time per second...      
    long y=System.currentTimeMillis()-start; //start is initialized on the onCreate

    if (isBetween(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)), 1000, 1070)) {
        time.setText("3");
        time.setAnimation(anim);
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)));
    } if (isBetween(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)), 2000, 2070)) {
        time.setText("2");
        time.setAnimation(anim);
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)));
    }else if (isBetween(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)), 3000, 3070)) {
        time.setText("1");
        time.setAnimation(anim);
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)));
    }else if (isBetween(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)), 4000, 4070)) {
        time.setText("GOOO!");
        time.setAnimation(anim);
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)));
        count.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        cuenta = 0;
        count.setText("0");
    }else if (isBetween(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)), 5000, 5070)) {
        time.setText("1");
        time.setAnimation(anim);
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)));
    }else if (isBetween(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)), 6000, 6070)) {
        time.setText("2");
        time.setAnimation(anim);
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)));
    }else if (isBetween(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)), 7000, 7070)) {
        time.setText("3");
        time.setAnimation(anim);
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)));
    }else if (isBetween(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)), 8000, 8070)) {
        time.setText("4");
        time.setAnimation(anim);
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)));
    }else if (isBetween(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)), 9000, 9070)) {
        time.setText("5");
        time.setAnimation(anim);
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)));
    }else if (isBetween(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)), 10000, 10070)) {
        time.setText("Time!");
        time.setAnimation(anim);
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(Long.toString(y)));
        //count.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        int finalcount = cuenta;
        System.out.println(finalcount);
    }
}
```

Any ideas about what can I change to see the animation correctly? I think that the times are well, at final, the animations have a duration of 700ms, and are started every 1000ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to make the animation scale your number to twice the size and then shrink it back to the original size.  What you have there, however, is two animations happening at the same time.  One animation does the shrinking and the other animation does the expanding.  This is causing a conflict.

What you need to do is have two animation files. Start one animation, and in the animation listener when the first animation is done, start the second animation.

Comment: Don't work, I try it adding a setAnimationListener, and don't work.

Comment: Did you break out your animation code to only one scale tag per file?  What happens?

Comment: yeah, I create another layout file that have the second scale animation (and i deleted from the first this). Also inside every if I created an AnimationListener of anim, to put inside the onAnimationEnd method the startAnimation of the second xml animation file.